# how to make jquery validation work on inputs and selectors

Tags: jquery, html

i have a form and i want to make jquery validation on it ,i made the
    jquery code and used validation plugin but when i press submit, it
    work on inputs only and dont work on select.. dont know what is the
    problem this is a screenshot that illustrate what i want to say
 [screenshot for the form validation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wpAsH.png)
       and here is my form code

```
    <form id="myForm" name="myForm" method="post" action="">
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
  <div class="form-group">
       <label>الدولة<span>*</span></label>
   <select class="form-control" name="country" id="country" >
  <option>اختر الدوله </option>
       <option>مصر </option>
       <option>الكونجو </option>
</select>
  </div>
     <div class="form-group">
    <label>اسم المدينه(عربي)<span>*</span></label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="text" name="cityName" id="cityName" >
  </div>

    </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
  <div class="form-group ">
       <label>المحافظة<span>*</span></label>
   <select class="form-control" >
  <option>اختر المحافظه </option>
</select>
  </div>
     <div class="form-group">
    <label>اسم المدينه(انجليزي)</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="cityName1" >
  </div>

    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
          <div class="form-footer">
          <input type="submit" id="submit" value="submit">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">الغاء</button>
          </div>       
      </div>
</form>
```

**and here is my jquery code** i really want to know what i miss here gUys !

```
    $(document).ready(function(){

   $("#myForm").validate({
      rules:{

          'country':{

              required:true,
          },

          'cityName':{

              required:true,
          }
      }, 

    messages:{
         'country':{

              required:"هذا الحقل الزامي",
          },

          'cityName':{

              required:"هذا الحقل الزامي ",
          }


    }

   });

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think for the validation to works your dropdown html should be like

```
<select class="form-control" name="country" id="country">
 <option value="">Choose an option</option>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
  </select>
```